# Can not see files from Docker in Zeppelin

Tags: apache-spark, docker, apache-zeppelin

I'm using Docker for a course about Spark.

I've set up my environment like this:

```
docker pull bigdatauniversity/spark2
docker run -it --name bdu_spark2 -P -p 4040:4040 -p 4041:4041 -p 8080:8080 -p 8081:8081 bigdatauniversity/spark2:latest /etc/bootstrap.sh -bash
```

Then I exited Docker and ran this:

```
docker start  bdu_spark2 
docker attach bdu_spark2
```

Now, when I go into Zeppelin I can't find the files given for the course.

I tried finding out if there is another Zeppelin process running at another port so I ran in the Docker console:

```
docker ps
```

However, the command `docker` is not recognised:

```
bash: docker: command not found
```

I also tried running `docker exec -it docker ps` but I got the same result.

So how can I see the files from the Docker container in Zeppelin?

Comment: Did you try running the second command ? You should use this one as it sets the container properly (port forwarding, init script).